# Kotlin: Generic Parameter on Classes and how they are resolved

Tags: generics, kotlin, types

My question is in the following example, why does the kotlin compiler not know the real type of 'fromParam'?

```
open class S<R>(val param : R)
class A : S<B>(B())
class B

fun <R> test(value : S<R>, param : R) {
    when(value) {
        is A -> {
            val fromClass : B = value.param 
            val fromParam : B = param // <- compiler error, found R required B
        }
    }
}
```

Okay so 'fromClass' has a concrete type 'B' because when you switch over the type like that there is an implicit cast, right? But by the same token it should be able to know that 'param' must be of concrete type 'B' when value is an 'A' because the generic parameters must be the same. So how come I can't use 'param' as a B in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Because the designers didn't decide to support it. This would indeed be valid (so far as I can see), but all existing smart casts only apply to the tested value. So it probably would be non-trivial to add, and how often would it be used?

This kind of type refinement is supported by [generalized algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_algebraic_data_type), which are supported in Haskell and OCaml (and somewhat in Scala), but their type system and type inference is quite different from Kotlin.